# two stage heat pump and condensing boiler run off one 3rd gen thermostat

Tags: wiring, heating, heat-pump, cooling

I have a 2 stage 20 seer bosch heat pump utilizing aux heat strip. I also have a navien condensing combi unit for domestic and hot water baseboard heating. no hydronic coil to air handler. Boiler only heats baseboards. Currently both systems are set up for two zones utilizing nest 3rd gen thermostats for both zones. The boiler is set up for emergency heat setting and the heat strip is set up for aux heating. One issue is when I turn the emergency heat on (boiler) the air handler fan kicks on as well. Is there a way to not have the airhandler fan kick on while using the boiler? How should this be wired?
Link is pictures of both systems. https://imgur.com/a/COawdQN

Comment: Barring highly unusual relative energy costs, the choice of aux/emergency sources seems odd.

Comment: If your HVAC contractor can't figure this out (comments in the Imgur album), it's likely beyond DIY skills, even crowdsourced-from-the-Internet DIY skills.

Comment: So i get the set up is very odd. The heat pump with electric aux was put in last year. i did not like how the house was heated. The duct work is in the ceilings, all the heat traveled up the stairwell which made the temperatures in the house very inefficient (to hot upstairs while cold downstairs). so i decided to install the boiler in replace of the old one that no longer worked. i still would like to utilize the heat pump in mild winter conditions and use the boiler when colder. Also i am not looking to wire myself. looking to provide feedback to contractor that i get from you guys.

Comment: Just as a FYI: you could get rid of the heat strips by using a hydronic coil off the boiler in your AHU in their stead for aux heat...that said, I can see where you're going here given that your AHU and ducts are set up for cooling, not heating.  (P.S. are said ducts in a vented attic?)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel- Thank you for the feedback. Yes, I have heard of the hydronic coil in place of the heat strips. Unfortunately this wont change how the heat is distributed through out the house since the duct work is set up for cooling. So I went back to baseboard heating for the colder days. Yes the attic is well vented. I would like both systems to operate correctly off of one t-stat per zone. Do you have suggestions on why my AHU fan would be coming on when boiler is turned on?

Comment: @Brian -- can you check for 24V between G and C at the air-handler when the system is set for Emergency Heat?  I'm wondering if the issue is that your zone board is assuming it always needs to drive G on heat pumps in emergency heat mode...